# Laravel 10 test email connection with EsmtpTransport class

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, symfony-mailer

I am trying to test a email connection with a user given configuration but I can't seem to find a way to test the connection. I get an error everytime I try to test it with a TLS encryption. If I change the port to a SSL one and the encryption to SSL it works, but I want to get it working with TLS too. I noticed that even when the port is set to the one TLS uses and the encryption is set to TLS it still adds "ssl://.." to the URL, I have no idea if this is what causes the problem or how to solve it.

I am using Laravel 10 and the `Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport\Smtp\EsmtpTransport` class.

Really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

```
ssl://smtp.gmail.com:587": stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

Here's how I try to test it:

```
// smtp.gmail.com
$host = Setting::where('key', 'email_host')->firstOrFail()->value;

// 587
$port = Setting::where('key', 'email_port')->firstOrFail()->value;

// my-username
$username = Setting::where('key', 'email_username')->firstOrFail()->value;

// my-app-password
$password = Setting::where('key', 'email_password')->firstOrFail()->value;

// TLS (or SSL)
$encryption = Setting::where('key', 'email_encryption')->firstOrFail()->value;

$tls = ($encryption == 'tls') ? true : false;

$transport = new EsmtpTransport($host, $port, $tls);
$transport->setUsername($username);
$transport->setPassword($password);

try { $transport->start(); }
catch (\Exception $e) { ... }
```

Comment: `ssl://` is prefixed here: https://github.com/symfony/mailer/blob/7b355fca167fa5302c77bccdfa0af4d7abc6bd8c/Transport/Smtp/Stream/SocketStream.php#L139 - no clue why. Maybe Symfony means SSL with the TLS option and you mean STARTTLS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the parameter `$tls` might be confusingly named.
SSL and TLS is synonym.

When setting `$tls = true` indeed `ssl://` is prefixed to the host, meaning a SSL encryption is used. [See here in the code](https://github.com/symfony/mailer/blob/7b355fca167fa5302c77bccdfa0af4d7abc6bd8c/Transport/Smtp/Stream/SocketStream.php#L139).

What you seem to try to do is to use `STARTTLS` this happens automatically based on the port and if SSL is off.

See also https://talk.octobercms.com/t/smtp-starttls-and-mail-encryption-in-laravel-9/1041

So passing `$tls = false` should do the job and use `STARTTLS`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Your right in it being a bit confusing. Thought the $tls param actually meant TLS encryption. But solution worked, just reversed the logic. Thank you! Been stuck on this for days. :joy: